# Get rid of inner join,but without losing structure

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Now i have the next query:

```
select a.*,b.* from
(select id,
sid,
start_date,
end_date from table_1 where code_id = 1001) a
inner join
(select id,
sid,
start_date,
end_date
from table_1 where code_id = 1002) b
on a.id=b.id
```

How can i rewrite this query without inner join and get the same result?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh you were right about " old-fashioned implicit one". Many answers here were with using "implicit one". I meaned that we should get the result like if we were using join but without join tables. Ive got a right decision. It was from user @leftjoin. He didnt join tables, he worked only with one table (`table_1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INNER JOIN can work as filter, also it can duplicate rows, depending on your data.
Use analytic function to calculate flag = 1 if 1002 record exist for id. Then filter using this flag:

```
    select s.* from
    (select id,
    sid,
    start_date,
    end_date, 
    max(case when code_id = 1002 then 1 end) over(partition by id) as has_1002 --1002 exists for this id flag,
     --if you need values for record with code_id = 1002 the use this
    max(case when code_id = 1002 then sid end)  over(partition by id) as sid_1002
    --and so on for all columns 
    from 
        table_1 
    ) s
    where code_id = 1001 
      and has_1002 = 1 --id partition contains code_id = 1002
```

Actually, this is not exactly the same, because your INNER join theoretically can duplicate rows if it is possible to exist more than one record with code_id = 1002 for the same id. This query with analytic max() will not duplicate rows. If your data contains no duplication, then INNER join will not duplicate rows and this solution will produce the same result. If you need possible duplication then INNER JOIN is right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are expecting row by records. Use union in that case

```
select id,
sid,
start_date,
end_date from table 1 where code_id = 1001
union all
select id,
sid,
start_date,
end_date
from table 1 where code_id = 1002
```

If you required column based records, you need to use join or a sub query. Let me know if this is your requirement. Or are you expecting below?

```
select 
t1.id,t1.sid,t1.start_date,t1.end_date,t2.id,t2.sid,t2.start_date,t2.end_date
from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t1.code_id = 1001 and t2.code_id = 1002;
```

Comment: I dont want to use various table joins, like 'on' or '='. Now im getting result with using two subquery ('a' and 'b' - and after inner join im getting result). But how can i get the same result without join subquery? Without using two separate subquery. I want to use only one subquery. Sorry for my bad english, but i hope it was a good explanation=)

Comment: select 
id,sid,start_date,end_date
from table1
where code_id in (1001,1002); Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: No, because after join you get 8 attributes(a.id,a.sid,a.start_dt,a.end_dt,b.id,b.sid,b.start_dt,b.end_dt). But after using `where code_id in (1001,1002)` you get only 4 attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write any query that uses an inner join by making a cross product and then filtering with what would have been the `on` clause of the join.

So, those two are identical:

```
Select a.*, b.*
  from a
  inner join b on a.id = b.id
```

And:

```
Select a.*, b.*
  from a, b
  where a.id = b.id
```

Why exactly you'd do that I don't know. It's a strange question.

Comment: I dont want to use various table joins, like 'on' or '='. 
Now im getting result with using two subquery ('a' and 'b' - and after inner join im getting result). But how can i get the same result without join subquery? Without using two separate subquery. I want to use only one subquery. Sorry for my bad english, but i hope it was a good explanation=)

Comment: @DenisPlotnikov I still do not understand. In the second example I show, there is no `join`. Either way, what you normally do when you write an SQL question is that you show the data and explain what results you expect, in addition to showing what you tried. Ideally, you use a _minimal_ example (so get rid of columns that are not relevant to your problem).

Comment: The second query is a join, an old-fashioned implicit one.

Comment: @jarlh Sure. However, do _you_ know what OP really needs and why?

Comment: @User9213, that remains a mystery.

Comment: @User9213 sorry for my bad explanation. See the solution from user @leftjoin.
He workes with only one table (one subquery),and without using join (he uses analytic function). In your solution  `inner join...on...` and `a.id=b.id` has the same meaning. You work with 2 "tables" (a and b) and you join this tables. User @leftjoin uses only 1 table ('table_1') and analytic function.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query.

```
select 
t1.id,
t1.sid,
t1.start_date,
end_date from table_1 t1, table1 t2
where t1.code_id = 1001 and t2.codeid=1002
and t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: That's a join, an implicit one.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as 
(
select id,
sid,
start_date,
end_date from table_1 where code_id in (1001,1002)
)


select a.*, b.* 
from cte a join cte b on a.id = b.id where a.code_id = 1001 and b. code_id = 1002
```